# Is my new battery really new and matching my laptop?

Tags: power-management, battery, thinkpad

I bought a new laptop battery for my aging Thinkpad T400 laptop from ebay.

On Ubuntu 16.04, I open power manager which gives me the following information:

```
Model 92P1137
Technology Lithium ion
Current charge 100%
Fully charged (design) 48.8 Wh
Fully charged 45.2Wh(92%)
Voltage 12.5V
Vendor SANYO
Serial 57
```

1. Is it normal that a new battery has "Fully charged" which is 92% of
   "Fully charged (design)" instead of 100%? Is my new battery really a
   new one?

   http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/check-battery-life-health-ubuntu-linux
   says that

   > Unless you’re using a brand-spanking new battery fresh out of its
   >   wrapper you will see a discrepancy between these two numbers. This is
   >   normal. The larger the gulf between the numbers the lower the charge
   >   your battery will be able to hold. If you scroll down further you’ll
   >   also find a percentage gleaned from the ratio of the above two
   >   numbers: the original capacity to the current capacity.

   My new battery is supposed to be new, but there is a discrepancy
   (92%). So does it mean that the new battery is not actually new?
2. My old battery that came with my laptop says 10.8V 5.2AH  57WH

   My new battery   says  model T61 (while Ubuntu's power manager
   says its model is 92P1137) and 11.1V 5.2Ah 58Wh

   I wonder if the new battery is a match to my laptop (T400)?

Thanks.

Comment: We don't know and can't know whether the battery you bought is actually new. Please contact the seller. In any case this looks like a hardware issue and unrelated to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

The slight voltage differences indicate different (and likely newer) chemistries. The "design" fully charged is what ever was speced out for your model and there are variances in manufacturing as well as aging in warehouses that could affect that. However there's no reason the battery won't just kept charging if you leave it long enough. It is indicating "fully charged" because of the voltage across the cells is high enough its drawing very little current.

Comment: Thanks.     (1) http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/check-battery-life-health-ubuntu-linux     says that " Unless you’re using a brand-spanking new battery fresh out of its wrapper you will see a discrepancy between these two numbers. This is normal. The larger the gulf between the numbers the lower the charge
   your battery will be able to hold.  "
    
    My new battery is supposed to be new, but there is a discrepancy
    (92%). So does it mean that the new battery is not actually new?

Comment: (2) The new battery says "Model T60", and the ebay seller claims it works for T400 laptop. But I notice there is difference in their voltage and power parameters (see the second part of my post). Is the new battery a match to T400?

Answer (score 2):

I too had one of my new laptop battery showing up as 94% of design charge even when i gave a full long charge, the first time. Probably didn't try to mess up with it and just left it there. It's still the same number and working well.

Answer (score 0):

Modern system use smart chargers. With a smart charging system, the battery tells the charger how fast to charge it and when it is full.

To increase battery life and prevent over charging. The battery will normally tell the charger it is full just short of it's designed capacity. Thus, the difference seen in the two values given.

Comment: not true; smart charger is just a bogus marketing cheat; because the charger has to supply power for laptop function all the time while it's connected; the `smart` resides in the fact that it has an identifier chip which often burns and when it does you have to buy(becouse if that identifier chip is burnt the bios of your laptop wont charge the battery and will throttle your cpu frequency.. see DELL horror stories) a new charger although the old one still works; all laptop batteries have protection circuits that cut the charge when presumed full

Comment: @user688056 -- I mean the charging circuits not the physical power supply. The power supply identifier is different than SMART Battery charging